# Java Object/Type is always giving me errors when I work on a different class

Tags: java, class, types

So my assignment is to basically create the game "Hearts" on the computer using java.

I first created an object "card" as such:

*

> public class Card {
>
> ```
>     public enum Suit {
>         CLUBS,
>             HEARTS,
>             SPADES,
>             DIAMONDS
>     }
>     public enum Value {
>         TWO,
>             THREE,
>             FOUR,
>             FIVE,
>             SIX,
>             SEVEN,
>             EIGHT,
>             NINE,
>             TEN,
>             JACK,
>             QUEEN,
>             KING,
>             ACE}
>
>
>       private Suit suit;  
>           private Value value;
> ```
>
> >
>                 public Card(Suit suit, Value value){
>           suit = getSuit();
>           value = getValue(); } }

Whenever i try to use the type Suit or Value in another class, however, I get the error "cannot be resolved to a variable". All the .java files are in the same folder, and I don't have any error messages on my Card class... So what am I doing wrong? Why won't java recognize the Value and Suit types?

PS: the other class is a test class the teacher gave us. I can't change it, because its the one he will be using to grade us.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you importing Suit and Value enums properly in the class you are using?

Comment: What line of code causes the error? Is it in your teacher's code your your own?

Answer (score 1):

You can access all inner (static) classes as well as enums by adding the class name in front:

`Card.Suit` will do the trick.

Comment: I can't though, because I would have to do that on the test file... however, he's the one using the test file not me. I need to find a way to change my code so that him simply writing "Value" instantly calls up that

Comment: Can't you put your enums in a separate file (each)?

Answer (score 0):

Try Card::Suit.  I'm not sure about the syntax.

Comment: I can't do that though, because its the file that my teacher is using. I need to modify something on this class.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your Suit and Value enums in separate files outside of the Card class:

In Suit.java:

```
public enum Suit {
    CLUBS,
    HEARTS,
    SPADES,
    DIAMONDS
}
```

In Value.java:

```
public enum Value {
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    ...
}
```

Then in Card.java, your Card class would start out something like this:

```
public class Card {

    Suit suit;
    Value value;

    public Card(Suit suit, Value value)
    { 
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
    } 
}
```